# Is there any way to execute test in parallel Using PageFactory framework?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, thread-local, page-factory

I want to execute Test in parallel. I have PageFactory Framework. When I execute scripts in parallel things gets messy. driver instance gets overwritten.

**LocalDriveFactory.Java**

```
package com.pom.framework;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import com.pom.listeners.TestListener;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class LocalDriverFactory {

protected String WORKINGDIR = System.getProperty("user.dir");
static {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");
    String logPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Log";
    System.setProperty("current.date.time", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    System.setProperty("logPath", logPath);
}

static WebDriver createInstance(String browser) {
    WebDriver wbDriver= null;
    EventFiringWebDriver driver;
    TestListener eventListener;
    JavascriptExecutor js;



    if(browser.equals("FF")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().arch32().setup();
        wbDriver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }else if(browser.equals("Chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();;
        wbDriver=new ChromeDriver();
    }

    driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(wbDriver);
    eventListener = new TestListener();
    driver.register(eventListener);

    js = (JavascriptExecutor)wbDriver;
    return driver;
}

public void navigate(String url) {
    LocalDriverManager.getDriver().navigate().to(url);
}
}
```

**LocalDriverManager.java**

```
package com.pom.framework;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class LocalDriverManager {


 private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }

    static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        webDriver.set(driver);
    }
}
```

implemented IInvokedMethodListener to call createInstance() method of DriverManager as below -

```
public class WebDriverListener extends LocalDriverFactory implements IInvokedMethodListener  {


    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {



        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");
            System.out.println(browserName);
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(browserName);
            LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
        }
    }

    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**sample test script -**

```
public class TestScript1{
@Test
@Parameters("URL")
void firstMethod(String url) {

      WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
      driver.get(url);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      HomePage hp = new HomePage(driver);


}
```

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage {

private WebDriver driver;

public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
     this.driver = driver;
     PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

WebElements & methods


}
```

driver is getting overwritten when we call page method. I have test class whci contains more than one @Test
How can we execute test in parallel using PageFactrory?

Comment: You aren't calling `createInstance()` from `LocalDriverManager`. When does it get called to create the instance and store it?

Comment: @JeffC I am using IInvokedMethodListener listener to create driver instance. i have updated the code

Comment: It's too hard to follow what all you are doing everywhere. You need to post a [mcve]. My suggestion is that you make a copy of your project and start deleting everything that isn't needed to reproduce the issue. Once you've done that, post your code. Things like log paths, pick one driver, `afterInvocation()`, etc. aren't needed to repro this.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is in `LocalDriverManager.java`. `getDriver()` should check and see if `webDriver` is `null`. If it is, then call `createInstance()`, stuff that driver into `webDriver` and return it. That should be the one and only place you call `createInstance()` in your code. See if that helps and let us know.

Comment: Another caveat when using pageobjects in parallel (but you don't show your page object so I don't know if you're encountering this) is to NOT declare your elements as static.  If you do, you will get collisions when multiple instances of the driver access the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I would run Java Selenium Webdriver tests in a Unit Test framework, such as JUnit or TestNG. They have built-in abilities to run tests in parallel. I would say no more than 2 browsers per CPU core. There is plenty of info on the web.